# C++11 STL unique function, but in reverse

Tags: c++, iterator, unique, predicate, deque

Is there a function which operates like `std::unique`, but that takes a custom comparison predicate, and retains the *last* element in an equivalent sequence, instead of the first?  The answer is yes if C++14 or C++17 is an option; however I am using C++11.

I am starting with a deque of large heavy objects, sorted by one lightweight field.  Some objects have equal values for the lightweight field, and this is unacceptable.  I need to discard all but the *last* object in any sequence with a matching light field.

At present my code calls `equal_range` using a custom *binary* predicate and a helper heavy object, then rewinds the end iterator:

```
deque<Heavy> heavyDeque(...);

Light helperLight(...);
Heavy helperHeavy(helperLight, );

typedef deque<Heavy>:: iterator HevIt;

pair<HevIt, HevIt> deleteRange = equal_range(
    heavyDeque.begin(), heavyDeque.end(), helperHeavy,
    [](const Heavy & lhs, const Heavy & rhs) {
        return lhs.getLight() < rhs.getLight()})

//I have prior knowledge of at least one match
assert(deleteRange.first != deleteRange.second);
// back up; don't delete the last one
--(deleteRange.second);
heavyDeque.erase(deleteRange.first, deleteRange.second);
```

I am not too happy with having to pass in `helperHeavy`, when all I need from inside it is `helperLight`.  I would rather my code look like this:

```
pair<HevIt, HevIt> deleteRange = magical_range_search(
    heavyDeque.begin(), heavyDeque.end(),
    [helperLight](const Heavy & heavy) {
        return helperLight == heavy.getLight()})
```

Note that my imaginary magical function takes a *unary* predicate, not a binary one.

Comment: Use reverse iterator?

Comment: If I understand right, you want to get from a superset, the last element of all sets found in the superset?

Comment: @KillzoneKid, it seems that my compiler and cplusplus.com both tell me that std::unique takes only ForwardIterators.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz yes, that sums it up correctly.  I want to do this operation with minimal copy/move ops, because the objects are heavy.

Comment: @KevinHencke I think you are mistaken https://ideone.com/MgTzHd

Comment: @ChristopherPisz thank you for the example (and that amazing website, wow!), but it's in C++14; that's not an option for me.  Does this still work in C++11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this, perhaps?

```
template<typename BidirectionalIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
pair<BidirectionalIterator,BidirectionalIterator>
magical_range_search(BidirectionalIterator begin,
                     BidirectionalIterator end, UnaryPredicate p)
{
  return {find_if(begin,end,p),
          find_if(make_reverse_iterator(end),make_reverse_iterator(begin),p)};
}
```

But, of course, for the whole thing you can just use `std::unique` with a `reverse_iterator`, as indicated in the comments:

```
heavyContainer.erase(heavyContainer.begin(),
                     unique(make_reverse_iterator(heavyContainer.end()),
                            make_reverse_iterator(heavyContainer.begin()),
                            [](Heavy const&lhs, Heavy const&rhs) {
                                return lhs.getLight() < rhs.getLight();
                            }).base());
```

Here `reverse_iterator<>::base()` returns the underlying original iterator of the `reverse_iterator` returned by `unique()`. As `unique()` returns the new end of the sequence, the reverse operation returns the new begin of the sequence. The new range is `{new_begin, orignal_end}`, and the elements in the range `{original_begin, new_begin}` must be `erase()`d.

Comment: I liked the look of your second suggestion, but got the following error message:
    error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::reverse_iterator<std::_Deque_iterator<Heavy, Heavy &, Heavy *>>" to "const std::_Deque_iterator<Heavy, Heavy &, Heavy *>" exists

Comment: I'm working on trying your first suggestion; would that solution break down if a match is absent?  Would we wind up with &*return.second < &*return.first because they'd seek past each other to end() and rend()?

Comment: @KevinHencke Referring to the usage of `unique()` with `reverse_iterator`: you would need to be careful when interpreting the returned iterator (`reduced`) in my answer. It's obviously a `reverse_iterator`, so will not automatically convert to the original iterator type, but for that you can use `base()`. I'll amend my answer.